# Last Step of a Parametric to Cartesian Conversion

Tags: linear-algebra, parametric

[image]

I need to figure out how to combine the (4) line to make the t=y-z/R+x and I just don't have any ideas. I'm sorry if these seem basic but I'm 16 and struggling through a topic I've never done before.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Just FYI though you have this tagged as "Cartan geometry," that is something entirely different. [Cartan geometry](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cartan_connection) is essentially geometry modelled on homogeneous spaces, such as conformal geometry, projective geometry, etc.

Answer (score 1):

Just add the two equations together:
$$2(z+Rt)+2tx=y(1+t^2)+y(1-t^2)$$
Simplify both sides:
$$2z+2Rt+2tx=2y$$
Divide both sides by $2$:
$$z+Rt+tx=y$$
Subtract both sides by $z$:
$$Rt+tx=y-z$$
Factor out a $t$ from the left side:
$$t(R+x)=y-z$$
Divide both sides by $R+x$:
$$t=\frac{y-z}{R+x}$$

Comment: Of course.. sorry I've been working for about 15 hours I think my productivity isn't what it could be. Thank you for being so clear in the explanation as well

Comment: @user2733843 Glad I could help!